# I would like to resize a window/image in a nib at load time

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad, xib

I have an iPhone app that I'm porting to the iPad.  I store several of the ViewControllers in xib's that I would like to resize when they're loaded.  For example my startup screen with options is a bitmap that can easily scale up (despite the mis-matched aspect ratio) and I'm trying to figure out where I have ability to resize the image/window during xib loading.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resizing the nib on load, you should create an iPad version in Interface Builder by "File → Create iPad version Using Autoresize Masks".

To modify the loaded view in run-time, implement the [`-viewDidLoad` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) in your view controller.